# Centring a Column inside another Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm currently writing my first Flutter App and I got a little stuck here. Basically what I'm trying to do is display an **image at the top** of the screen (with 100px top-margin) and display a **Column** which contains some Text and a Button on the **centre** of the screen. I tried moving `mainAxisAlignment` `crossAxisAlignment` into the outer Column Widget but that centres everything.

Here's my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.25,
          child: Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            width: 75,
          ),
        ),

        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Please enter your first name:'),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Submit'))
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually only need to wrap the second column in an [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget, "so that the child fills the available space", that's all:

```
Column(
    children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
                children: [],
            ),
        )],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

try, wrap your second Column inside a Center widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.25,
          child: Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            width: 75,
          ),
        ),

        Center(
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Please enter your first name:'),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Submit'))
          ],
        )
      ],
     ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

If this doesn't work you could also wrap it in an Align widget and add the alignment property to it.

```
Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Please enter your first name:'),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Submit'))
            ],
          ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
  MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.pink,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use mainAxisAlignment property to set MainAxisAlignment.center.

Answer (score 0):

In order to center align your second column,

1. Make sure MainAxisAlignment of your Second Column is MainAxisAlignment.center
2. Wrap your second column inside a Align Widget
3. Now, wrap your Align widget with Expanded widget.

This should solve your issue.

Check this refrence.

```
 Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      const SizedBox(
        height: 18.0,
      ),
      const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
        child: Text(
          'Recent Search(s)',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                MdiIcons.magnify,
                color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                size: 72.0,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              Text(
                'Search for places',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              Text(
                'You haven\'t serached for any items yet...',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              Text(
                'Try now - we will help you!',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
```