# Flutter a Column inside a Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a column inside a column.

I encountered with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73581531/7880054

But it did not solve my problem.

This code still gives error in a column.

```
   Expanded(
                                      child: Column(
                                    children: const <Widget>[
                                      Text('Deliver features faster'),
                                      Text('Craft beautiful UIs'),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: FittedBox(
                                          child: FlutterLogo(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
```

How can I solve my problem? I'm trying to implement a column inside a column.

**ERROR:**

It is going to Flex.dart and showing this code:

```
 @override
  void performLayout() {
    assert(_debugHasNecessaryDirections);
    final BoxConstraints constraints = this.constraints;
    assert(() {
      final FlutterError? constraintsError = _debugCheckConstraints(
        constraints: constraints,
        reportParentConstraints: true,
      );
      if (constraintsError != null) {
        throw constraintsError;
      }
      return true;
    }());
```

**Yellow line:**

```
throw constraintsError;
```

Comment: Expanded() widgets must be a child of a Row() or Column(). Is this the case for your topmost widget? Also, what is the error output?

Comment: Scaffold.......

Comment: I edited my question you can look. Thank you.

Comment: Just curious, if you were to refactor the top Expanded widget to Column, do you get the same error?

Comment: you can try flex property of expanded and give it value `Expanded(flex:1)` and see if the error is gone